# Flutter + firebase is it safe?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm building a Flutter based Android, iOS app and I have social auth as a login option using Firebase authentication. Then I will have a separate table `user_roles` that will define who has admin access in the app, and those admins will be able to see certain specific features in the app.

As we have to attach google-services.json in the app so anyone can read it. I understand that there will be security rules in the Firebase through which we can control who can read/write. My biggest worry is if some attacker uses my google-services.json in their app, log in using social auth, and then try to add him/her in the `user_roles` table or try to retrieve user data from other tables.

Comment: It's very clear here what exactly you are considering to be "safe".  Yes, your Firebase config is public after you ship your app, but that doesn't give anyone privileged access to your project.  You do have to use security rules to make sure authenticated users can read and write your database by your specific permissions, but without seeing those rules and the underlying data, we can't really say anything.

Answer (score 1):

Not the complete answer I guess, but we can restrict to some extent using firestore security rules as you have mentioned.

In my app, there are only few admins and we have their email ids. So when a request comes to user_roles table any write request is going to check the email ids and if the request contains only that email id then it is allowed.

Also most of the cases I only  allow soft delete meaning none of the collections are enabled for delete in the security rules, only a flag is set for deletion and I do not read those flagged when I query. or I move the deleted documents into a new deleted collection and hence manage the delete part.

But as you said, it is possible for user to read the other data from your app. In fact they can use the listCollections api and get all collections and read the docs in there. So do not know if this is ok for you or maybe somebody can correct me..

Comment: that means someone can even see who are the admins in the app, which is concerning

Comment: That depends on how you implement the security rules. Without seeing yours, it's hard to help more than p2hari already did.